# UWP Store Services SDK Advertising

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, uwp, uwp-xaml

So a few months ago my UWP app was successfully displaying test banner ads with AdMediator and Advertising SDK for XAML. 
Then MSFT went ahead and wrapped Advertising up into the Store Services SDK and even though I followed the setup instructions and can successfully build, ad's never show up. Anyone?

The frame shows in the XAML file the ad does not get filled however, I have not changed anything on the Microsoft Developer Portal from when things worked. My control tag is:

```
<Universal:AdControl Name="XXXXXX" ApplicationId="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" AdUnitId="XXXXXXXX" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="{Binding ElementName=gridMain, Path=ActualWidth}" Margin="0,265,0,5" />
```

I have the advertising namespace at the top of the XAML file:

xmlns:Universal="using:Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI"

Comment: Which control did you use for displaying your ad? And by `ad's never show up` what you mean? Just the ad doesn't show or the control together with ad doesn't show?

Comment: Hi Grace, thanks for your comment, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `Universal:AdControl`, then you want to create a banner ad, banner ad must have a fixed size, you can refer to the [supported banner ad size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/supported-ad-sizes-for-banner-ads?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) .

By the way, [ActualWidth property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is not a dependency property, it cannot be used for data binding. So it could be the problem that you didn't actually give the `Universal:AdControl` any size. Please try to set the size of this control to 300x250 and see if it works. If not, please provide more details for this issue and leave a comment.

Comment: Hi Grace, I did have banner ads and with the admediator and ads for universal apps sdk it was all working.  Wish MSFT would make up there mind with sdks,  anyway I'll give it a shot. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Grace, size was indeed the issue, I am not sure why it worked with the old sdks. Thanks again